# A shared online code viewing tool with syntax highlighting?

Tags: php, shared, pastie

I work with another developer on projects and sometimes we are chatting about them via IM. We can dropbox stuff back and forth, but it would be nice to have like an interactive version of pastie / google docs where we could see the same code and edit it together with syntax highlighting.

I know Cloud9IDE has something like this, but I am looking for a real-simple, realtime (if possible), shared textarea with PHP syntax highlighting. Does that exist?

UPDATE
This is what i was looking for: http://collabedit.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://collabedit.com/

is probably what your looking for.

Answer (score 2):

[ShiftEdit](http://shiftedit.net/) will be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a great solution:
http://phpanywhere.net/overview/

I haven't tried it, They should have real time collobration soon, but you can share and work on projects togheter with this.

Answer (score 0):

I find [github is pretty cool](https://github.com/) for collaboration between developpers. This is a very personnal opinion though, some of the  friend developpers I have never got into using git so that is a show stopper with this platform. It may not be what you had in mind, though.

Comment: No, unfortunately my answer does not address this requirement asked your answer. Sorry. Still a great platform, though.

Comment: Though to be fair none of the answers seem to offer real-time code editing _and_ sharing capabilites.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about the realtime-edit, but have look @ https://join.me/ to share screens

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget codepad, it allows your code to be tested online.

http://codepad.org/